# C++ key input in Windows console

Tags: c++, windows, input

I'm currently developing various **console** games in Windows that won't really work using regular input via `cin`.

How can I (In a simple way using only standard windows libraries available in MSVC):

- Make the program wait for a (specific?) key press and return the key ID (It would have to work for all keys including the arrow keys)
- During a real-time game check for the last pressed key of the user and if there was any key pressed since the last check.

It would really help if you could include a short example program for your solution

Comment: "How do I inflate a bicycle tire with a potato?" cin was not designed for games - use Windows API.

Comment: "How do I inflate a bicycle tire with a potato?" - I wasn't asking anything about how I should use cin for creating console games. I wanted to prevent suggestions on using cin for text-based games instead of anything more complicated. Thanks for the very helpful comment, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do it using the standard C runtime.  You will need to use something such as the Win32 function [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` reads globally, even if the app isn't in focus. It is blocked my AV for making the app look like a keylogger.

Answer (score 2):

I've got just what you need.

Here enjoy pal:
[C++ source](http://pastebin.com/D6VqiiXw)

It's pretty much self-explanatory but if you have any doubts my email is jacobossm@gmail.com

Comment: will this trigger even if the console window has no focus?

Answer (score 1):

You want the Windows Console API, for example [PeekConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684344%28VS.85%29.aspx).