# C++ controls for a game running in windows console

Tags: c++, c, user-controls, keyboard, c++-cli

I'm trying to make a small 2 players game that runs in the command prompt. All things were good  until I've started working on players controls. So, for capturing the keyboard keys I thought the best solution would be the use of getch() function. That's because getch() takes keys on the fly, without displaying it on screen, waiting for enter or other keys to be pressed.

The code to accomplish that, as far as I could think, is fairly simple:

```
c=getch();
switch(c)
{
case 'a': make player 1 go left
          break;
case 'd': make player 1 go right
          break;
case 's': make player 1 go down
          break;
case 'w': make player 1 go up
          break;
case 'h': make player 2 go left
          break;
case 'k': make player 2 go right
          break;
case 'j': make player 2 go down
          break;
case 'u': make player 2 go up
          break; 
}
```

everything being inside a while loop of course.

The thing is I need both players to be able to move while the controls are pressed at the same time. With getch() when player 1 moves right after player 2 presses the key assigned for left movement for example, player 1 blocks player 2 as they both keep pressed the movement keys. Of course if player 2 releases the key and presses another key assigned, he takes control on movement while blocking player 1, and so one.

To make myself a bit more understood, with a code looking like this:

```
c=getch();
switch(c)
{
case 'a': cout <<"a";
          break;
case 'd': cout <<"b";
          break;
}
```

when someone keeps 'a' key pressed the output will be "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", and after someone else presses 'b', even if the first person keeps his hold on 'a', the output will become "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb". If the first person releases 'a' and presses it again the output would be "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" as the other one holds 'b'. For my game to work, when they both keep pressed 'a' and 'b', I believe the output should be something like "ababababababababab".

Honestly I've tried everything I could think so far, but I'm new to C/C++ programming so maybe I just don't have enough experience with these programming languages to make it work. It's not necessarilly to make my getch()+switch() strategy work, any other suggestions would be welcomed just as well. But they'll have to resume to windows console.

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: `getch()` isn't suitable for such purpose. You'll need s.th. like `keypressed()` method. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246502/c-key-input-in-windows-console

Comment: It's not possible with plain console input, where only one key at a time is active. You have to find out when a key is pressed or released, and use flags to see which keys are currently pressed. I don't know if it's possible in the Windows console.

Comment: It is, ReadConsoleInput().  Gets you key up and down notifications.

Comment: Thanks  g-makulik, using GetAsyncKeyState(), did the trick, using if and else if clauses instead of switch. This way I had to cover all24 possible controls combinations of player 1 and player 2, but I finally have what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Your thinking is correct. At the end of the day, it would probably look like this:

```
void Keypressed()
{
    if (kbhit())
    {
      keypress =getch();
        switch (keypress )
        {

            case key_F1:
                displayHelp();
            break;

            case key_LEFT:


            case key_RIGHT:

            break;

            case key_UP:
                   PlayersPad.y-=3;if (PlayersPad.y<0) PlayersPad.y=0;
            break;

            case key_DOWN:
                   PlayersPad.y+=3;if (PlayersPad.y>18) PlayersPad.y=18;
            break;

            case key_ENTER:
            break;

            case key_SPACE:
            break;

            case key_TAB:
                autoPlay=-autoPlay;
                if (autoPlay>0)
                {
                    setcolor(79);gotoxy(62,23);printf("cheat on  " );setcolor(15);
                }
                else
                {
                    setcolor(79);gotoxy(62,23);printf("cheat off  " );setcolor(15);
                }

            break;


        }
    }

}
```

[image]

And as an added bonus, here is code to a Pong game i have written, its  a player vs player or player vs computer.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream.h>

#define Black 0
#define Blue 1
#define Green 2
#define Cyan 3
#define Red 4
#define Magenta 5
#define Yellow 6
#define White 7
#define Gray 8
#define LightBlue 9
#define LightGreen 10
#define LightCyan 11
#define LightRed 12
#define LightMagenta 13
#define LightYellow 14
#define BrightWhite 15

#define key_F1 59
#define key_UP 72
#define key_DOWN 80
#define key_LEFT 75
#define key_RIGHT 77
#define key_SPACE 32
#define key_ENTER 13
#define key_ESCAPE 27
#define key_TAB 9
#define key_INSERT 82
#define PONG_WIDTH 78
#define PONG_HEIGHT 22
#define PONG_SCREEN_RIGHT PONG_WIDTH-3
#define PONG_SCREEN_LEFT 5
#define PONG_SCREEN_TOP 2
#define PONG_SCREEN_BOTTOM 22

struct t_ball{ int x,y,headingX,headingY;};
struct t_pad{ int x,y,LEFT,RIGHT;};
int temp,kbChar;
int _key=0;
unsigned long   OldTicksPerSecond=GetTickCount(),NewTicksPerSecond=GetTickCount();
unsigned long   PreferredFramesPerSecond;
unsigned long   DeltaTicksPerSecond;
unsigned int frames=0;
float fps=60.0f;
float Refesh;
float InverseFramesPerSecond;
float OneFramePerSecond;
int keypress=0;

t_ball ball;
t_pad  PlayersPad,computersPad;
int  autoPlay,playersScore,computersScore;


void moveBall();
void runGame();
void initGame();
void Keypressed();
void gameLogic();
void removeBall();
void displayHelp();
void displayYouMissed();
void displayCheatEnabled();
void Render_Game_At_60_Frames_Per_Second();

void getKey();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void setcolor(WORD color);
void textColor(unsigned char fColor,unsigned char bColor);
void clrscr();
void delay(int milliseconds);

void txtPlot( unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char Color);
void txtLine( int xx1, int yy1, int xx2, int yy2 ,int color);
void clrbox(unsigned char x1,unsigned char y1,unsigned char x2,unsigned char y2,unsigned char bkcol);
void box(unsigned x,unsigned y,unsigned sx,unsigned sy,unsigned char col,unsigned char col2,char text_[]);
void putbox(unsigned x,unsigned y,unsigned sx,unsigned sy,
                 unsigned char col, unsigned char col2,unsigned char bkcol,char text_[]);

int main()
{

    runGame();

  return 0;
}







/*********************************
 * runGame()
 ********************************/

void  runGame()
{
    initGame();
    while (keypress !=key_ESCAPE)
    {
        Keypressed();
        gameLogic();
        moveBall();
        Sleep( 50  );

        removeBall();
        setcolor(31);gotoxy(7,22);printf("ball  X=%d,Y=%d ",ball.x,ball.y );setcolor(15);
        setcolor(31);gotoxy(7,23);printf("pad   X=%d,Y=%d ",PlayersPad.x,PlayersPad.y );setcolor(15);
        setcolor(31);gotoxy(32,22);printf("Your Score:       %d ", playersScore );setcolor(15);
        setcolor(79);gotoxy(32,23);printf("Computers Score:  %d ", computersScore );setcolor(15);
    }

}
/*********************************
 * moveBall()
 ********************************/

void moveBall()
{

    txtPlot( ball.x,ball.y,15);
    txtLine(PlayersPad.x,PlayersPad.y,PlayersPad.x,PlayersPad.y+3,15);
    txtLine(computersPad.x,computersPad.y,computersPad.x,computersPad.y+3,15);


}
 /*********************************
 * removeBall()
 ********************************/

void removeBall()
{
    //Sleep( 9  );
    txtPlot( ball.x,ball.y,0);
    txtLine(PlayersPad.x,PlayersPad.y,PlayersPad.x,PlayersPad.y+3,0);
    txtLine(computersPad.x,computersPad.y,computersPad.x,computersPad.y+3,0);

}
 /*********************************
 * gameLogic()
 ********************************/

void gameLogic()
{
    /* update ball's x location */
    ball.x+=ball.headingX;
    /* update ball's y location */
    ball.y+=ball.headingY;

    /* if ball at most right of screen then reverse ball's x heading */
    if( (ball.x>PONG_SCREEN_RIGHT) )
    {
        ball.headingX=-ball.headingX;
        computersScore+=10;
    }
    /* check if ball's location at top or bottom of screen,if true reverse ball's y heading */
    if( (ball.y<PONG_SCREEN_TOP) || (ball.y>PONG_SCREEN_BOTTOM-2) ) ball.headingY=-ball.headingY;

    PlayersPad.LEFT=PlayersPad.y-3;
    PlayersPad.RIGHT=PlayersPad.y+5;

    /* check if ball lands on pad, if true bounce back */
    if ( (ball.y>= PlayersPad.LEFT) && (ball.y<= PlayersPad.RIGHT) && (ball.x==PlayersPad.x))
    {
        ball.headingX=-ball.headingX;
        playersScore+=10;
    }
    /* let computer track ball's movement */
    if (ball.x>PONG_SCREEN_RIGHT-18) computersPad.y=ball.y;

    /* if cheat enabled,let player track ball's movement */
    if (autoPlay>0)
    {

        if (ball.x<PONG_SCREEN_RIGHT-50) PlayersPad.y=ball.y;
        if (ball.x>PONG_SCREEN_LEFT+16)
        {
            if (PlayersPad.y<10) while (PlayersPad.y<10) PlayersPad.y++;
            if (PlayersPad.y>12) while (PlayersPad.y>10) PlayersPad.y--;
        }

    }
    /* check if ball misses pad, if true display you missed */
    if (ball.x<PONG_SCREEN_LEFT)
    {
        displayYouMissed();
        ball.x=75;
        ball.y=15;
        computersScore+=10;

    }
}

/*********************************
 * initGame()
 ********************************/

void  initGame()
{

    playersScore=0;
    computersScore=0;
    ball.x=15;
    ball.y=5;
    ball.headingX=1;
    ball.headingY=1;

    PlayersPad.x=5;
    PlayersPad.y=12;
    computersPad.x=75;
    computersPad.y=12;


    displayCheatEnabled();

    setcolor(15);
    clrscr();
    txtLine(6,0,74,0,1);
    txtLine(6,22,74,22,1);
    txtLine(6,23,74,23,1);

        autoPlay=1;
    if (autoPlay>0)
    {
        setcolor(79);gotoxy(62,23);printf("cheat on  " );setcolor(15);
    }
    else
    {
        setcolor(79);gotoxy(62,23);printf("cheat off  " );setcolor(15);
    }

    setcolor(31);gotoxy(62,22);printf("<F1> Help" );setcolor(15);
}

void displayHelp()
{
    clrbox(10,8,70,16,79);
    box(10,8,70,16,31,79,"Pong Game, Player vs Computer");

    gotoxy(18,10);cprintf("Controls  ");
    gotoxy(18,11);cprintf("<LEFT>   move pad left");
    gotoxy(18,12);cprintf("<RIGHT> move pad right");
    gotoxy(18,13);cprintf("<TAB>  cheat mode ON/OFF");
    gotoxy(18,15);cprintf("press any key to continue");
    keypress =getch();
    clrbox(10,8,75,21,0);



}

void displayYouMissed()
{
        clrbox(10,8,70,16,79);
        box(10,8,70,16,31,79,"You missed");

        gotoxy(18,10);cprintf("  ");
        gotoxy(18,11);cprintf("The ball has missed the paddle");
        gotoxy(18,12);cprintf("press press space to continue");
        gotoxy(18,13);cprintf("");
        gotoxy(18,14);cprintf("");
        keypress =getch();
        clrbox(10,8,75,21,0);


}

void displayCheatEnabled()
{
        clrbox(10,8,70,16,79);
        box(10,8,70,16,31,79,"Player vs. Computer");
        gotoxy(15,10);cprintf("The Cheat' pad will track  ball movement' is enabled");
        gotoxy(15,11);cprintf("press <TAB> to enable or disable the cheat.");
        gotoxy(15,13);cprintf("press press space to continue");
        gotoxy(18,14);cprintf("");
        gotoxy(18,14);cprintf("");
        keypress =getch();
        clrbox(10,8,75,21,0);


}

/*********************************
 * Keypressed()
 ********************************/

void Keypressed()
{
    if (kbhit())
    {
      keypress =getch();
        switch (keypress )
        {

            case key_F1:
                displayHelp();
            break;

            case key_LEFT:


            case key_RIGHT:

            break;

            case key_UP:
                   PlayersPad.y-=3;if (PlayersPad.y<0) PlayersPad.y=0;
            break;

            case key_DOWN:
                   PlayersPad.y+=3;if (PlayersPad.y>18) PlayersPad.y=18;
            break;

            case key_ENTER:
            break;

            case key_SPACE:
            break;

            case key_TAB:
                autoPlay=-autoPlay;
                if (autoPlay>0)
                {
                    setcolor(79);gotoxy(62,23);printf("cheat on  " );setcolor(15);
                }
                else
                {
                    setcolor(79);gotoxy(62,23);printf("cheat off  " );setcolor(15);
                }

            break;


        }
    }

}

/*********************************
 * Render_Game_At_60_Frames_Per_Second()
 ********************************/

void Render_Game_At_60_Frames_Per_Second()
{
    NewTicksPerSecond=GetTickCount();
    DeltaTicksPerSecond=NewTicksPerSecond-OldTicksPerSecond;
    frames++;

    if(DeltaTicksPerSecond>=PreferredFramesPerSecond)
    {


        OldTicksPerSecond=NewTicksPerSecond;
        InverseFramesPerSecond=1/((float)PreferredFramesPerSecond/1000.0f);
        OneFramePerSecond=(float)frames*InverseFramesPerSecond;
        fps+=OneFramePerSecond;
        fps/=2;
        setcolor(31);gotoxy(70,22);printf(" %d FPS ",DeltaTicksPerSecond );setcolor(15);
        frames=0;
        Refesh=60/fps;
    }
    Sleep(3);
}





        //*****************************************************************************
        //*                                                                           *
        //*****************************************************************************

        void gotoxy(int x, int y)
        {
            COORD coord;
            coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
            return;
        }
        //*****************************************************************************
        //*                                                                           *
        //*****************************************************************************

        void setcolor(WORD color)
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
            return;
        }


        //
        //     colors:
        //     0 = Black
        //     1 = Blue
        //     2 = Green
        //     3 = Cyan
        //     4 = Red
        //     5 = Magenta
        //     6 = Yellow
        //     7 = LightGray
        //     8 = DarkGray
        //     9 = LightBlue
        //     10 = LightGreen
        //     11 = LightCyan
        //     12 = LightRed
        //     13 = LightMagenta
        //     14 = LightYellow
        //     15 = White


        //

        void setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(int ForeGroundColor,int BackGroundColor)
        {
           int color=16*BackGroundColor+ForeGroundColor;
           setcolor(color);
}



        //*****************************************************************************
        //*                                                                           *
        //*****************************************************************************

        void clrscr()
        {
            COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };
            DWORD cCharsWritten;
            CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
            DWORD dwConSize;
            HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

            GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
            dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
            FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, TEXT(' '), dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
            GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
            FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, csbi.wAttributes, dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
            SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
            return;
        }
        //*****************************************************************************
        //*                                                                           *
        //*****************************************************************************

        void box(unsigned x,unsigned y,unsigned sx,unsigned sy,unsigned char col,unsigned char col2,char text_[])
        {  unsigned i,j,m;
            {

               m=(sx-x);                       //differential
               j=m/8;                          //adjust
               j=j-1;                          //more adjustment
               gotoxy(x,y);cprintf("É");       //Top left corner of box
               gotoxy(sx,y);cprintf("»");      //Top right corner of box
               gotoxy(x,sy);cprintf("È");      //Bottom left corner of box
               gotoxy(sx,sy);cprintf("¼");     //Bottom right corner of box

               for (i=x+1;i<sx;i++)
               {
                  gotoxy(i,y);cprintf("Í");     // Top horizontol line
                  gotoxy(i,sy);cprintf("Í");    // Bottom Horizontal line
               }

               for (i=y+1;i<sy;i++)
               {
                  gotoxy(x,i);cprintf("º");     //Left Vertical line
                  gotoxy(sx,i);cprintf("º");    //Right Vertical Line
               }

                  gotoxy(x+j,y);cprintf(text_); //put Title
                  gotoxy(1,24);
            }
        }
        //*****************************************************************************
        //*                                                                           *
        //*****************************************************************************

        void clrbox(unsigned char x1,unsigned char y1,unsigned char x2,unsigned char y2,unsigned char bkcol)
        {
            int x,y;
            setcolor(bkcol);                       //Set to color bkcol

            for (y=y1;y<y2;y++)                    //Fill Y Region Loop
            {
                for (x=x1;x<x2;x++)               //Fill X region Loop
                {
                  gotoxy(x,y);cprintf(" ");       //Draw Solid space
                }
            }
        }
        //*****************************************************************************
        //*                                                                           *
        //*****************************************************************************

        void putbox(unsigned x,unsigned y,unsigned sx,unsigned sy,
                 unsigned char col, unsigned char col2,unsigned char bkcol,char text_[])
        {
            clrbox(x,y,sx,sy,bkcol);
            box(x,y,sx,sy,col,col2,text_);
        }

        //*****************************************************************************
        //*                                                                           *
        //*****************************************************************************


        void txtPlot( unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char Color)
        {
                setcolor(Color);
                gotoxy(x,y);cprintf("Û");
        }


    //**********************************************
    //**                                          **
    //**********************************************




         void  txtSwap(int first, int second )
        {
          int  temp ;


            temp   = first;
            first  = second;
            second = temp;
          }




     void txtCircle(int X, int Y, int rad, int col)
     {
       float deg = 0;
       do {
         X = (int) (rad * cos(deg));
         Y = (int) (rad * sin(deg));
         txtPlot (40+X, 12+Y,  col);
         deg +=  0.005;
       }
       while (deg <= 6.4);
     }


    //**********************************************
    //**                                          **
    //**********************************************



    void txtLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int color)
    {
        int pix = color;
        int dy = y1 - y0;
        int dx = x1 - x0;
        int stepx, stepy;

        if (dy < 0) { dy = -dy;  stepy = -1; } else { stepy = 1; }
        if (dx < 0) { dx = -dx;  stepx = -1; } else { stepx = 1; }
        dy <<= 1;                                                  // dy is now 2*dy
        dx <<= 1;                                                  // dx is now 2*dx

      txtPlot( x0, y0,pix);
        if (dx > dy) {
            int fraction = dy - (dx >> 1);                         // same as 2*dy - dx
            while (x0 != x1) {
                if (fraction >= 0) {
                    y0 += stepy;
                    fraction -= dx;                                // same as fraction -= 2*dx
                }
                x0 += stepx;
                fraction += dy;                                    // same as fraction -= 2*dy
                txtPlot( x0, y0,pix);
            }
        } else {
            int fraction = dx - (dy >> 1);
            while (y0 != y1) {
                if (fraction >= 0) {
                    x0 += stepx;
                    fraction -= dy;
                }
                y0 += stepy;
                fraction += dx;
                txtPlot( x0, y0,pix);
            }
        }
    }


    //**********************************************
    //**                                          **
    //**********************************************




        void delay(unsigned int milliseconds)
        {
            clock_t ticks1, ticks2;
            unsigned int tic1=0,tic2=0,tick=0;

            ticks1=clock();
            while(tick<milliseconds)
            {
                ticks2=clock();
                tic1=ticks2/CLOCKS_PER_SEC-ticks1;
                tic2=ticks1/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
                tick=ticks2-ticks1;
            }
            ticks2=clock();
        }
```