# How to make movable character in maze with C++

Tags: c++, user-controls

So I have my maze printed out once the user presses 1 in order to launch the map and other variables. I have declared the player as a smiley face or set equal to 1. However, I would like to make this character movable throughout the maze but am having trouble doing so. I have created a player move as a space in order for it to move without overwriting other code. I was thinking of using a switch statement and detecting user input and then changing the X and Y positions based on that but I dont know how to put it in my mapCreation function. I was also wondering if you guys could help me generate the variables such as treasures at random locations throughout the map and if it is a wall or '|' then dont print. My treasures spawn but at the same location. Any input on any of my questions would really help! Thank you!

** Ignore the cases as they were just being used previously but now I dont have a use for them.

**UPDATE
If anyone has a link somewhere that would help that would also be helpful! Thank you!

```
// Header Files
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>


using namespace std; 

HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); // For use of SetConsoleTextAttribute()


#define LEVEL_COUNT (2)
const char* maze[LEVEL_COUNT][12] = 
{
        {
            "||||||||||||\n",
            "|       |  |\n",
            "|       |  |\n",
            "|    ||||  |",
            "|          |",
            "|          |",
            "||||||     |",
            "| |        |",
            "| |    |   |",
            "|      |   |",
            "|      |   |",
            "||||||||||||",
        },
       {
            "||||||||||||",
            "|       |  |",
            "|   |||||  |",
            "|       |  |",
            "|          |",
            "|       ||||",
            "|          |",
            "|   |      |",
            "|   |      |",
            "|||||||    |",
            "|          |",
            "||||||||||||",
        }, 
};

// Function Prototypes

void titleScreen(); // Prints Title and instructions

void mapCreation( char arr[][12], int level);

void drawMap(char arr[][12]);

bool update(char arr[][12], int &level, int &lives, int &score);

void loadMap( char arr[][12], int level);

// Player Struct
struct Player{
    int x;
    int y;
    char move;
};



// Main Program
int main ()
    {
    // initialize variables
    int option;
    char baseMap[12][12];
    int level = 1;
    int lives = 3;
    int score = 0;
    bool gameOver = false;
    bool levelCompleted = false;


    SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, 240); // change background to white

    system("CLS");// clears screen in order to remove black background

    titleScreen(); // Display Title

    do // do-while loop starts
    {

    cin >> option; // take in input

        if(option == 1) // temporary option to check for next screen
            {
            //Display Maze

            system("CLS");// clears screen in order to remove black background

                 mapCreation( baseMap, 1 ); // Create map, this one is map 1

                 drawMap(baseMap); // iterate throup the map and print it out
                    //   update(baseMap, level, lives, score);



             }
          if(option == 2)
            {
            //Display Maze

            system("CLS");// clears screen in order to remove black background

                 mapCreation( baseMap, 2 ); // Create map, this one is map 1

                 drawMap(baseMap); // iterate throup the map and print it out
                    //   update(baseMap, level, lives, score);
             }

        }
    while( option !=1); // condition of do-while loop

    system("pause"); // Pause for user, only temporary

    return 0;

}








void titleScreen(){

    cout << " Welcome to Treasure Hunter!\n\n";
    cout << "In order to beat this game you must find the treasure\n";
    cout << " that is located in the maze. You can move using the \n";
    cout << " arrow keys or WASD.\n\n";
    cout << " Warning! There are traps that will take life away as\n";
    cout << " well as add life! However, they are hidden so be careful!\n ";
    cout << " Goodluck and have fun!\n\n\n\n";
    cout << " Press Ctrl+C to quit\n";


}


void mapCreation( char arr[12][12], int level )
    {
      int traps = 0;   
      int lives = 0;
      int treasure = 0;
      int x ;
      int y ;
        for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
             for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
                {
                 arr[i][j] = 0;
                }

            }

        // load the map:
        loadMap(arr,level);

        switch (level)
        {
        case 1:




        break;

        case 2: // Level 2 Map

        break;
        }
    }

void drawMap(char arr[12][12])
    {
        // Declare variables to be prtined out
      Player player;
      player.x = 1;
      player.y = 1;
      player.move = ' ';
      int traps = 0;   
      int lives = 0;
      int treasure = 0;
      // Lives,Traps, and Treasure x and y positions
      int Trap_Y,Trap_X,Lives_X,Lives_Y,Traps_X,Traps_Y; 
      // Randomly place variables
      Trap_X = (rand() % 10);
      Trap_Y = (rand() % 10);  
      Lives_X = (rand() % 12);
      Lives_Y = (rand() % 12);
      Traps_X = (rand() % 12);
      Traps_Y = (rand() % 12);    

     for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
        cout << endl; // print out new line
         for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++ )
            {
                if(player.x == i && player.y == j)
                arr[player.x][player.y] = 1;                        




                // If variables are  not equal to a wall character print it out
                 if(arr[Trap_X][Trap_Y] != '|' )                         
                arr[Trap_X][Trap_Y] = 4; // treasure is 4
                treasure++;
                if(arr[Lives_X][Lives_Y] != '|')// traps are 2
                 arr[Lives_X][Lives_Y]= 2; 
                 traps++;
                if(arr[Traps_X][Traps_Y] != '|') // lives are 3
                 arr[Traps_X][Traps_Y]= 3;
                 lives++;


                cout << arr[i][j];

            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

/*bool update(char arr[][12], int &level, int &lives, int &score)
    {
     bool levelCompleted = false;
     bool gameOver = false;
    }
*/


void loadMap( char arr[][12], int level)
{
     if((level < 0) || (level >= LEVEL_COUNT))
         return;

     for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
     {
         const char* row = maze[level][i];
         for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
         {
             if(row[j] == 0)
                 break; // end of string
             if(row[j] == ' ')
                 arr[i][j] = 0;  // set spaces to zero
             else
                 arr[i][j] = row[j];
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I've done something like this in Linux before and the best thing to use for that was the ncurses library. It looks like there is a similar version called PDCurses for Windows. curses allows you to write characters to specific coordinates, which sounds like what you want.

Comment: I was wondering how I could use the curses, because I include it in my header but it isn't detecting it. Any ideas how I can include or have ncurses? Thanks for commenting too!

Comment: ncurses is a Linux library. Since you have included `windows.h`, I assume you do not have it. PDCurses is a third party library. You will have to download and install it.

Comment: Ok I installed it. Any links so I could learn how to use it relating to player movement?

Comment: I've never used PDCurses. Read the [documentation](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/doc/PDCurses.txt). If you look under "Input Values" you will see the keys you can get from the `getch()`. Also take note of the `keypad()` function. The other function you will be interested is `mvaddch()`. There are a few other setup and tear down functions you will need. From what I have read of the docs, it looks nearly identical to ncurses, so just google around for basic examples for either one and reference the documentation to double check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On windows, You can use `ReadConsoleInput()` to navigate with a keyboard in a windows console. This solution checks for collision using the statement `if (maze[player.y][player.x-1]==0)` . `0` means no wall, `1` means wall has been hit.

Here's an example of the usage of `ReadConsoleInput()`.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define VK_W 0x57
#define VK_S 0x53
#define VK_A 0x41
#define VK_D 0x44


struct t_player{ int x,y;};
t_player player;
char playersymbol=219;
char mazewall=0;
int mazex=31,mazey=8;

int maze[16][24] =
{{ 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
 { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};


void clrscr();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void setcolor(WORD color);
void textColor(unsigned char fColor,unsigned char bColor);
void moveleft();
void moveright();
void moveup();
void movedown();
void drawmaze(int px,int py);
void putmenu();
void putplayer();

int main()
{
    DWORD        mode;          /* Preserved console mode */
    INPUT_RECORD event;         /* Input event */
    BOOL         EXITGAME = FALSE;  /* Program termination flag */
    unsigned int counter = 0;   /* The number of times 'Esc' is pressed */


    /* Get the console input handle */
    HANDLE hstdin = GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE );

    /* Preserve the original console mode */
    GetConsoleMode( hstdin, &mode );

    /* Set to no line-buffering, no echo, no special-key-processing */
    SetConsoleMode( hstdin, 0 );


    player.x=20;
    player.y=13;

    clrscr();
    setcolor(15);


    while (!EXITGAME)
    {
        if (WaitForSingleObject( hstdin, 0 ) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)  /* if kbhit */
        {
            DWORD count;  /* ignored */

            /* Get the input event */
            ReadConsoleInput( hstdin, &event, 1, &count );

            /* Only respond to key release events */
            if ((event.EventType == KEY_EVENT)
            &&  !event.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)

            clrscr();
            putmenu();
            Sleep(100);


                switch (event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode)
                {
                    case VK_ESCAPE:
                       EXITGAME = TRUE;
                     break;

                    case VK_LEFT:
                        // left key   move player left
                         moveleft();
                     break;

                    case VK_RIGHT:
                        // right key   move player right
                        moveright();

                     break;    

                    case VK_UP:
                        // up key   move player up
                        moveup();

                     break;

                    case VK_DOWN:
                        // down key   move player down
                         movedown();

                     break; 

                    case VK_A:
                        // left key   move player left
                        moveleft();

                     break; 

                    case VK_D:
                        // right key   move player right

                        moveright();
                     break; 

                    case VK_W:
                        // up key   move player up

                        moveup();
                     break; 

                    case VK_S:
                        // down key   move player down
                        movedown();
                     break; 


                }//switch

                putplayer();


        }
    }

    gotoxy(1,23);cout<<"  ";  
    SetConsoleMode( hstdin, mode );
    return 0;
}

void putplayer()
{
    setcolor(9);
    gotoxy( player.x +mazex,    player.y  +mazey); 
    cout<<playersymbol;
    setcolor(7);

}


void putmenu()
{
    gotoxy(1,1);cout<<"keyboard navigator ";

    setcolor(14);
    gotoxy(31,1);cout<<"Use keys W,S, A,D, Left,Right,Up,Down ";

    setcolor(7);

    gotoxy(31,2);cout<<"W or up key = move player up ";
    gotoxy(31,3);cout<<"S or down key = move player down ";
    gotoxy(31,4);cout<<"A or left key = move player left ";
    gotoxy(31,5);cout<<"D or right key = move player right ";

    setcolor(11);

    drawmaze(mazex,mazey);
    setcolor(7);

}


void drawmaze(int px,int py)
{
    for(int y =0; y<16;y++)
    {
        for(int x=0; x<24; x++)
        {
           if (maze[y][x]==1) mazewall=219;
           else mazewall=32;

           gotoxy(x+px,y+py);
           cout<< mazewall;
        }

    }

}

void moveleft()
{
    gotoxy(31,7); 
    cout<<"left key   move player left    \n\n";
     if (maze[player.y][player.x-1]==0)   player.x = player.x -1;
}

void moveright()
{
    gotoxy(31,7); 
    cout<<"right key   move player right   \n\n";
     if (maze[player.y][player.x+1]==0)   player.x = player.x +1;
}

void moveup()
{
    gotoxy(31,7); 
    cout<<"up key   move player up      \n\n";
     if (maze[player.y-1][player.x]==0)   player.y = player.y -1;
}

void movedown()
{
    gotoxy(31,7); 
    cout<<"down key   move player down   \n\n";
     if (maze[player.y+1][player.x]==0)   player.y = player.y +1;

}



void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    return;
}

void setcolor(WORD color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
    return;
}




void setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(int ForeGroundColor,int BackGroundColor)
{
   int color=16*BackGroundColor+ForeGroundColor;
   setcolor(color);
}



void clrscr()
{
    COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };
    DWORD cCharsWritten;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD dwConSize;
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, TEXT(' '), dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, csbi.wAttributes, dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I implemented this into my code but when I move around it skips in 2 spaces instead of 1? This prevents me from getting the treasure if it is in a spot that player cant touch.

Comment: Yes,under windows its tricky  when using win32api, most games therefore use directx directinput, also you could use kbhit() and getch() contained in conio.h to go around this - see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019945/c-controls-for-a-game-running-in-windows-console/23721063#23721063